# BMR Calculator testing

Tags: java, math, testing, constructor, calculator

Was just finishing up a test class for a project on exercise and BMR when I got the error that it "cannot find symbol" while pointing at the second "BMR" while making each different person to use the test on. AFAIK the actual bmr class works fine because it doesn't give me any errors.

Test class:

```js
public class BMRTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person1", 123, 128, 30, 'm', 2);
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person2", 156, 115, 24, 'f', 1);
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person3", 136, 147, 19, 'm', 5);
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person4", 145, 192, 24, 'm', 4);
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person5", 125, 121, 44, 'f', 3);

    System.out.println("1" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("2" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("3" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("4" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("5" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
  }
}
```

Actual BMR Class:

```js
public class BMR {

  private String Name;
  private float weight;
  private float height;
  private int age;
  private char gender;
  private int exercise; //1-5

  //BP
  public BMR(String n, float w, float h, int a, char g, int e) {
    n = Name;
    w = weight;
    h = height;
    a = age;
    g = gender;
    e = exercise; //1-5
  }

  //CALCULATE
  public float calculateBMR() {
    float rv;

    if (gender == 'f') {
      rv = femaleBMR();
    } else {
      rv = maleBMR();
    }
    return rv;
  }

  //MALE BMR
  private float maleBMR() {
    return 66 + 6.23f * weight + 4.7f * height - 6.8f * age;
  }

  //FEMALE BMR
  private float femaleBMR() {
    return 655 + 4.35f * weight + 12.7f * height - 4.7f * age;
  }

  //EXERCISE ADJUSTMENT
  public float calculateBMRWithExcercise() {
    float rv = 0;
    float bmr = calculateBMR();

    switch (exercise) {
      case 1:
        rv = bmr * 1.2f;
        break;

      case 2:
        rv = bmr * 1.375f;
        break;

      case 3:
        rv = bmr * 1.55f;
        break;

      case 4:
        rv = bmr * 1.725f;
        break;

      case 5:
        rv = bmr * 1.9f;
        break;

      default:
        System.out.println("Error");
        break;
    }
    return rv;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to have so many `BMR bmr1`. You must define a different variable name for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your test code, you are trying to declare the same object multiple times.  Try creating a separate object for each of your test cases like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person1", 123, 128, 30, 'm', 2);
    BMR bmr2 = new BMR("Test Person2", 156, 115, 24, 'f', 1);
    BMR bmr3 = new BMR("Test Person3", 136, 147, 19, 'm', 5);
    BMR bmr4 = new BMR("Test Person4", 145, 192, 24, 'm', 4);
    BMR bmr5 = new BMR("Test Person5", 125, 121, 44, 'f', 3);

    System.out.println("1" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("2" + bmr2.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("3" + bmr3.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("4" + bmr4.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("5" + bmr5.calculateBMRWithExercise());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your BMRTest main method, you should create 5 BMR objects with 5 individual names. Instead you declare them all with the name "bmr1", which is likely causing the error. Try changing it to something like this:

```js
public class BMRTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BMR bmr1 = new BMR("Test Person1", 123, 128, 30, 'm', 2);
    BMR bmr2 = new BMR("Test Person2", 156, 115, 24, 'f', 1);
    BMR bmr3 = new BMR("Test Person3", 136, 147, 19, 'm', 5);
    BMR bmr4 = new BMR("Test Person4", 145, 192, 24, 'm', 4);
    BMR bmr5 = new BMR("Test Person5", 125, 121, 44, 'f', 3);

    System.out.println("1" + bmr1.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("2" + bmr2.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("3" + bmr3.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("4" + bmr4.calculateBMRWithExercise());
    System.out.println("5" + bmr5.calculateBMRWithExercise());
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah I saw that as soon as I posted this but that doesn't solve the issue unfortunately. Seems I also missed the fact that I saved the two in different folders as I was exploring into a subfolder when I saved the test class.

Comment: Does the issue persist? If so, what is the error and at what line does it occur at?

Comment: Well, now it prints out the same error but pointing at the period inbetween each bmr(number).calculateBMRWithExercise().

Comment: Well there definitely doesn't appear to be any sort of syntactical error. As long as you imported your BMR class in your BMRTest file, I don't see why there would be an error.